# How can I normalize data and create a stacked bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, normalize

I have a data frame containing total sales of each game genre in 3 regions. I would it to create a stacked bar chart so that I can make a comparison of the sales of each genre across each region.

I know that I should normalize the data first, but have no idea how to.

I am very new to programming, so I would appreciate it if someone can provide a simple explanation on how I can go about doing this!!

This is my dataframe

```
regional_genre = video_sales_df.groupby(['Genre'],as_index=False)["NA_Sales","EU_Sales","JP_Sales"].sum()[:5]
```

Dataframe:

```
Genre       NA_Sales   EU_Sales   JP_Sales
Action      877,83     525        159,95
Adventure   105,8      64,13      52,07
Fighting    223,59     101,32     87,35
Misc        410,24     215,98     107,76
Platform    447,05     201,63     130,77
```

I used [:5] because I only want to plot the top 5 genres in each region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably something that you are trying to achieve. You can use sklearn for normalization and see below how to create a stacked bar plot. Use the normalization scale that you want.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Read data
video_sales_df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

regional_genre = video_sales_df.groupby(['Genre'],as_index=False)["NA_Sales","EU_Sales","JP_Sales"].sum()[:5]
columns = ["NA_Sales","EU_Sales","JP_Sales"]

# Normalization parameters
normalize_min = 0.1
normalize_max = 1

# Normalize
regional_genre[columns]= preprocessing.minmax_scale(regional_genre[columns], feature_range=(normalize_min, normalize_max))

# Plot stacked bars
plt.bar(regional_genre["Genre"], regional_genre["NA_Sales"], label="NA_Sales")
plt.bar(regional_genre["Genre"], regional_genre["EU_Sales"], bottom=regional_genre["NA_Sales"], label="EU_Sales")
plt.bar(regional_genre["Genre"], regional_genre["JP_Sales"], bottom=regional_genre["EU_Sales"]+regional_genre["NA_Sales"], label="JP_Sales")
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel("Normalized sales")
plt.show()
```

[image: result2]

Another solution:

```
# Plot stacked bars
plt.bar(columns, regional_genre.ix[0,1:], label="Action")
bot = regional_genre.ix[0,1:]
plt.bar(columns, regional_genre.ix[1,1:], bottom=bot, label="Adventure")
bot += regional_genre.ix[1,1:]
plt.bar(columns, regional_genre.ix[2,1:], bottom=bot, label="Fighting")
bot += regional_genre.ix[2,1:]
plt.bar(columns, regional_genre.ix[3,1:], bottom=bot, label="Misc")
bot += regional_genre.ix[3,1:]
plt.bar(columns, regional_genre.ix[4,1:], bottom=bot, label="Platform")
plt.show()
```

[image: result2]

Comment: Hi Artoiss, thank you very much for your reply! This is very close to what I want. May I know, instead of Genres, how I can put Sales as the x-axis? If that makes any sense...

Comment: Do you mean how to plot 3 bars that contain 5 levels of data in the bar? Or kind of rotating the figure by 90 degrees when x-axis would be normalized sales?

Comment: Do you mean how to plot 3 bars that contain 5 levels of data in the bar? >> Yes. So normalized-sales will be on the y-axis, but on the x-axis I would like NA-sales, EU-Sales and JP-sales. The levels of data would be the genres.

Comment: Or do you think, from an analysis point of view, having a stacked bar chart like what you did initially, would make more sense? I am trying to figure out what is the most sensible way to display the data.

Comment: Like this: https://imgur.com/a/gpVjxDr ?
I think that both of these ways are ok. What I did here was I stacked all the data in the rows instead of columns. I will append this the code under the previous solution.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Thank you so much for your help! I was really stuck. Appreciate it!!! I believe this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use from sklearn.preprocessing the function MinMaxScaler

Transforms features by scaling each feature to a given range.